# How can I dynamically index through datalayer tags in GTM?

Tags: javascript, arrays, wordpress, google-tag-manager

I'm using the DuracellTomi datalayer plugin to push cart data from woocommerce to a GTM model to handle some tracking.

The DuracellTomi plugin pushes content to the transactionProducts[] array in the following format:

```
transactionProducts: Array[1]
0 : Object
category:""
currency:"USD"
id:8
name:"Test"
price:100
quantity:"1"
sku:8
```

I'd like to loop through this array and unstack it into three separate arrays, pricelist, skulist, and quantitylist. Currently I anticipate doing so as some variation on

```
  //Get Product Information
  if(stack = {{transactionProducts}}){
    for(i = 0; i < stack.length; i++) { 
        if(stack.i.sku){
            skulisttemp.i = stack.i.sku;
            }
      if(stack.i.price){
            pricelisttemp.i = stack.i.price;
            }
      if(stack.i.sku){
            quantitylisttemp.i = stack.i.quantity;
            }
        }
    {{skulist}} = skulisttemp;
    {{pricelist}} = pricelisttemp;
    {{quantitylist}} = quantitylisttemp;

    }
```

Obviously this is not going to work because of how the tag referencing is set up, but I'm wondering if anyone has dealt with this and knows what the best way to index through these arrays might be. (For those who don't know, the square bracket array call doesn't work with GTM variables and instead the . format is used instead.)

Comment: Your last sentence ends in mid-air. There are situations where it might be more efficient to use pure Javascript in a custom HTML tag (evaluating GTM variables is an expensive operation) but it's hard to tell with that incomplete sentence. In any case you cannot assign variables that way, you'd have to use a datalayer.push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to create 3 variable type custom javascript function that picks your required value from dataLayer and returns it in an array.
Something like

```
function(){
var products =  {{transactionProducts}};
var skuArray = [];
for(i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    if(products[i].sku){
        skuArray.push(products[i].sku)
    }
}
return skuArray
```

}

hope this helped you :)

Comment: This is almost exactly what I ended up doing. Thanks for your response. Breaking down the variables into custom html really helps.